# How do I use Twig to create reusable form inputs?

Tags: php, forms, twig, code-reuse

I'm using PHP and Twig for an application in which I want to be able to have consistent form inputs across the site that are all rendered from one place in the code.

That is, I want all the form input generation markup to be in one place so that if/when I want to make a change to how the form inputs look and function across the entire site, I can change one thing in one place and have it take effect everywhere.

What's the best way to go about accomplishing this with Twig?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Use twig's `macro`

https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/macro.html

forms.html:

```
{% macro input(name, value, type, size) %}
    <input type="{{ type|default('text') }}" name="{{ name }}" value="{{ value|e }}" size="{{ size|default(20) }}" />
{% endmacro %}
```

usage:

```
{% import "forms.html" as forms %}
<p>{{ forms.input('password', null, 'password') }}</p>
```